PC switches on and off in a loop and some fans won't work
My electric recently got turned off and my PC wouldn't turn on and now all of sudden it does and everything looks fine but my CPU fan won't turn on and my PC switches off and immediately back on every like 15 seconds. My Corsair RGB fans work fine but I think the problem could be my motherboard?


If your CPU fan won't start turning, then your CPU is overheating quickly, and the shutdown is a protection. I would look into your CPU fan first before anything else. Is the power cable connected properly or is the fan just dead?
